# Where are the deleted files in CVS repository server?

Tags: cvs

I'm doing CVS repo archaeology, in fact I'm trying to get back a file directly from the CVS repo.

I looked in CVSROOT/history file and found that at some point in time, we had a file called "a.java" with version 1.4.

Now this file is no more, how does CVS index his files? I know for each revisioned file, we have a "FILE_NAME,v" which contains the changes. The deleted files should be somewhere, isn't it?

Thx a gazillion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delete a file from cvs that was previously versioned it should be in an `Attic` folder you should be able to move it from `<dir>/attic` to `<dir>`.

Here's more info on where to find the [attic](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/cvsmanual/Attic.html)

Comment: I don't have 'Attic' dirs. This is strange. Can they be somewhere else? I checked inside my repo and there is no attic.

Comment: We strongly believe we had tampering with our CVS repo, that is why I'm going all nuts about this

Comment: you did a find ./ -name "Attic" from the root ? you should have a bunch of them if its an active repository.

Comment: All the source code is in subdirectories on the same level as CVSROOT, the contain nothing but filename,v files. Inside CVSROOT I find configuration files and "history" which is full. I believe the ones who set up the CVS repo where not careful at all...